# C++ function to find minimum from a list . Is this function correct because the returned iterator gets invalidated

Tags: c++, list, templates, pointers, iterator

```
list<LNode>::iterator minI(list<LNode>::iterator start,list<LNode>::iterator end)
{
     list<LNode>::iterator min_index=start;

     for(auto it=start;it!=end;it++)
     {
        if(it->len<min_index->len)
            min_index=it;
     }
     return min_index;
}
```

in main()

..

```
    cout<<(&(*vnode.begin()))<<endl;
    auto min_it=minI(vnode.begin(),vnode.end());
    cout<<(&(*vnode.begin()))<<endl;
    cout<<(&(*min_it))<<endl;
    char ch;
    int i=min_it->i,j=min_it->j;
    printf("\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t",t1[i].from,t1[i].to,t1[i].flight,t2[j].city,t2[j].discount);
    scanf("%s",&ch);

    cout<<(&(*min_it))<<endl;
```

..

while the first three cout prints 0x600d88
the last cout prints 0x600d08
can anyone explain me the reason??

,,

Comment: Why do you think it the iterator gets invalidated?

Comment: You can do the same thing with C++11 lambdas in one line: `std::min_element(start, end, [] (LNode const & a, LNode const & b) { return a.len < b.len; })`, or prior to C++11 you can create a comparison functor. And no, the returned iterator is not invalid, unless you do something *after* this function returns that causes it to become invalid.

Comment: @jrok I think min_index is pointing to some local copy of some variable which ends with the function minI but i can't figure it out

Comment: @AviYadav It doesn't. Answer jrok -- *why* do you think it is being invalidated?

Comment: @AviYadav: No, it's an object in its own right, with valid copy semantics. It "points" to an element of the list, but doesn't depend on the existence of any other object.

Comment: I have edited my post to add some more information . Please have a look at that

Comment: @AviYadav: Perhaps `scanf("%s",&ch);` is reading more than one character and trashing the stack. Why on earth are you doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator doesn't get invalidated.

In general, iterators over standard containers can only be invalidated if the container is modified. In the case of `list`, they are only invalidated if the element they refer to is removed.

In the second snippet of code, `scanf` is given a pointer to a single character, but will overwrite at least two: any characters the user enters, followed by the terminator. This gives undefined behaviour, which might well modify the value of local variables (like `min_it`). Try replacing that with the safer C++ equivalent

```
std::string ch;
std::cin >> ch;             // to read one word, or 
std::getline(std::cin, ch); // to read a whole line
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem , I was giving only one character as input but i think null character is appended making it equivalent to two characters.

Comment: @AviYadav: Good point: it will add the null character, so you'll always get at least two (and always get UB). I've updated the answer.